# Why is my variable not registering in Unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner with C# and Unity. I am hoping someone can explain an issue I am having.
In the following code, inside the `FindingInventory` method I have a `foreach` with an `if` statement checking the key value against an int variable called `currentGold`.
When using `currentGold`, the debug prints out the entire dictionary but if I use another variable I created called `wallet` the check works correctly.
I do not see any issue with `currentGold` however.

**EDIT**: currentGold also will not update in the inspector from the first value I set.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class LearningCurve : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public bool pureOfHeart = true;
    public bool hasSecretIncantation = false;
    public string rareItem = "Relic Stone";
    public string characterAction = "Attack";
    public int wallet = 5;
    public int currentGold = 1;

    void Start()
    {

        //int characterLevel = 32;
        //int nextSkillLevel = GenerateCharacter("SPike", characterLevel);
        //int range = Random.Range(22, 44);
        //nt power = Damage(range);
        
        //Thievery();
        //OpenTreasureChamber();
        //PrintCharacterAction();
        //RollDice();
        //FindPartyMembers();
        FindInventory();

    //Debug.Log($"you hit for {power}");
        //Debug.Log(nextSkillLevel);
        //Debug.Log(GenerateCharacter("Faye", characterLevel));
    }

    public void FindInventory()
    {
         
        Dictionary<string, int> itemInventory = new Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                {"Potion", 5 },
                {"Antidote", 7 },
                {"Asprin", 1 }
            };
        itemInventory.Add("Throwing Knives", 3);
        itemInventory["Bandages"] = 5;
        itemInventory["Potion"] = 10;

        if (itemInventory.ContainsKey("Potion"))
        {
            itemInventory["Potion"] = 15;
        }

        itemInventory.Remove("Asprin");

        //int numberOfPotion = itemInventory["Potion"];
        //Debug.Log($"You have {numberOfPotion} potions in stock");
        //Debug.LogFormat("Party Member: {0}", QuestPartyMembers.Count);
        //Debug.LogFormat("Items: {0}", itemInventory.Count);

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in itemInventory)
        {
            //Debug.LogFormat("Item: {0} - {1}g", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            if(kvp.Value <= currentGold)
            {
                
                    Debug.LogFormat("you can afford" + kvp);
            }
        }
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: With `currentGold`, it should print nothing.  With `wallet`, it should print "Throwing Knives".  Is that not what you see?  Are you absolutely sure you didn't accidentally put a semicolon at the end of the `if`?

Comment: The code as posted here is fine, I copy pasted directly and it works.  So I would suggest that as "currentGold" is declared publicly, that this value is being altered outside of the Script either in your Unity editor or during the game.  Add a "Debug.Log" to output the value before you enter the loop and check what it is.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Comment: I don't see any connection whatsoever between your code and the public exposed fields tbh ... but in general these are serialiezed in the Inspector => In case you afterwards change their value in the code at field declaration it will do nothing as the serialized value from the Inspector overrules the default value.